# I click HOME button and the program minimizes; but when I press the app icon, the program is launched twice

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

I have the following problem:

When I press the Android HOME key, I can see the "Desktop" and my app icon. Then I press my app icon and my application launches twice. I don't want open my app twice.

How my program works:

I have 4 Activities (A, B, C, D).

A - The Main Activity: It is the first to open. It opens the other activity that has a lot of buttons. It's like a Java's main() method. I show a SplashScreen and I call another Activity. Then I **finish** my activity "A".

B - The Menu Screen: In this activity, I have some buttons, like a menu. I have a configuration button, update button, and Login Button. When I click the login button, I finish this activity and open the Login Screen (Activity "C").

C - The Login Screen: The user writes the Login and Password. If the login is successful, I finish this activity and open the Activity "D".

D - The application main screen: It stays opened all the time and launches another Activities. I finish this when I want close my application.

P.S.: I tried change the launchMode flag (androidManifest.xml), but didn't work.

My AndroidManifest.xml bellow:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="MyApplication">
    <activity android:name="A"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="br.com.site.B" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name="br.com.site.C" android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name="br.com.site.D" android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

And this is my Activity "A.java" source:

```
public class A extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AtualizaDadosFrame.class));
    }
}
```

**I don't want open my app twice.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean open your app twice? you don't want to see activities a-c again?

Comment: Did you launch your app initially (the first time) via an IDE (like Eclipse or IntelliJ)? How did you install the app on the phone?

Comment: Hi, David Wasser! The application is installed on the phone. By the way, this error occurs only on the phone.

Comment: OK, How did you install the application on the phone and how do you start the application the **first time**?

Comment: Hi, David! I copied the APK file to the phone, and I installed clicking on the APK file. After the application is installed, I click on the app icon to start it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you started the app initially (the first time) from an IDE (like Eclipse or IntelliJ). If so, this is a known bug in Android (see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658 ). Many people have struggled for days chasing this problem :-(

Please don't change the launchMode. This is not the correct way to solve this problem. The default (standard) launchMode is the one that works in most cases.

**EDIT (Added link to workaround):**

A simple workaround for this problem can be found at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373#c21

Comment: I didn't suggest that you change the launch mode. Did you have a look at the link I posted?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the desired [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict this.....
Please  go through below link.

[Home key press behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042420/home-key-press-behaviour/4782423#478242)